# How to connect PREV, NEXT pagination to WordPress, which would work only in its sub-categories?

Tags: wordpress

I have CPT(GALLERY), they have category(default category, not taxonomie). Categories - Face, Body, Legs, etc. And they have their own sub-categories (children). In the Face - Eyes, Ears, Cheeks.
I am including the get_previous_post and get_next_post function in the worpdress.
They have the $in_same_term parameter. If you specify true, it works for one category. But it also works for all subcategories associated with that category. Is it possible to make a Prev Next pagination that only works in its subcategories?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $category = get_the_category();
    $cats = array();
    if ($category) {
        foreach($category as $cat) {
            $cats[] = $cat->term_id;
        }
    }
    $postBefore = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type'       => 'photo_gallery',
        'category__and' => $cats,
        'posts_per_page' => 1000,
    ));
    $arrayPost = array();
    $next_url = '';
    $prev_url = '';
    if($postBefore->have_posts()) {
        foreach ($postBefore->posts as $item) {
            $arrayPost[] = $item->ID;
        }
    }
    foreach($arrayPost as $index => $postItem) {
        if($postItem === get_the_ID()) {
            $prev_url = isset( $arrayPost[ $index - 1 ] ) ? get_permalink($arrayPost[ $index - 1 ]) : '';
            $next_url = isset($arrayPost[$index + 1]) ? get_permalink($arrayPost[$index + 1]) : '';
            break;
        }
    }
    ?>
    <div class="navigation">
        <div class="prev-posts pull-left">
            <?php
            if($prev_url) {
                echo "\t" . '<a rel="prev" href="' . $prev_url .'" class=" h5"><strong>Previous Case</strong></a>' . "\n";
            }
            ?>
        </div>
        <div class="next-posts pull-right">
            <?php
            if($next_url) {
                echo "\t" . '<a rel="prev" href="' . $next_url .'" class=" h5"><strong>Next Case</strong></a>' . "\n";
            }
            ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).